# Spotify under Wine

Tags: drivers, wine, spotify

I am running Spotify under Wine. However, it keeps getting interrupted now and then, and I have to restart Spotify. (I am running **Ubuntu 10.10** and **Wine 1.2.2**).

How is this fixed?

I have tried switching from the `Alsa Driver` to the `OSS Driver` in the Wine configurations, but then I get a message that there is no sound card found.

Are there any others options?

---

I forgot to add; I only have a regular Spotify account, therefore I cannot use Spotify for Linux.

Comment: So now Spotify client for Linux requires a paid account while a Windows one doesn't? Strange. A few years ago when I was using it, both clients had the same functionality and you could perfectly use Linux client with a free account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a developing version for Linux for it here: http://www.spotify.com/int/download/previews/

It shows you step by step how to add the repository and install it.

A simple guid on how to solve "some" of the problems with Spotify is here: http://www.spotify.com/int/help/faq/wine/

And a testing done using the 1.3.x branch shows as Platinum here: http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=22244

Just to add, if you are using the 1.2 Stable branch i recommend moving to the 1.3 "Unstable branch". I have been testing it for several games, office products and the likes and works much better than the Stable one.

The install guide is here thanks to **Scott Ritchie**: http://www.winehq.org/download/deb

If you want to know what version you have just run in the terminal `wine --version`

Comment: I forgot to mention that I only have a regular Spotify account, hence why I am running Spotify through Wine. The only thing that seems to match my problem in Spotify's Wine-FAQ is the `OSS driver` part, which I have already tried. However, Updating Wine to 1.3.17 seems to work! At least for now. Thanks! :)

Comment: If you can, post this in the wine bugzilla. It will help devs solve the issue for you.

Answer (score 0):

My solution is to upgrade Wine to 1.3 with pulseaudio support built in - then Wine apps will play nice with all the other audio sources of Ubuntu.

Not sure if it works with 10.10, I can confirm it works with 10.04:

http://www.webupd8.org/2010/05/install-wine-with-built-in-pulseaudio.html

Comment: Well it is a bit inaccurate to say that Wine has ever had built-in support for PulseAudio - these two have been in "war" for a long time now. There was a driver made for Wine which routed audio through PulseAudio, but it is now "redundant" [ http://art.ified.ca/?page_id=40 ] so there is no use in having it. It is a mess, but we wait for the OpenAL plugin for wine gets done; it will solve the audio problems between PulseAudio and Wine - or so is said.

Answer (score 0):

You can download your Spotify songs via the tool [DumpMedia](https://www.dumpmedia.com/spotify-music-converter/). Then you won't get interrupted by Wine. Here are the steps for you:

1. **Download and Launch the DumpMedia Application**

   Before you can start using the application, of course, you need to download the software first. After downloading the DumpMedia installer, launch the application by following the steps below for Windows and macOS operating systems.
2. **Add Your Spotify Song to the Application**

   Add the URI of your Spotify song/playlist/album on the search bar or you can drag and drop your files to the application.
3. **Choose Your Desired Output Format and Destination Folder**

   Look for the *Convert all tasks to* text at the top right corner of the interface. Select your desired output format (FLAC, WAV, M4A, or MP3). At the bottom of the interface, click on the *Browse* button and browse your computer to the desired destination folder of the converted files.
4. **Start the Conversion Process**

   Click the *Convert* button to start the conversion of your Spotify music files. Wait for a few minutes and the conversion will be completed. Now all you need to do is to check out the converted files in your local folder.